# Android - Only show 1 value in Spinner from Adapter

Tags: android

I've got a spinner control that I'm populating from a class that inherits from a BaseAdapter.  I can use this adapter class to populate the spinner but it's showing 2 columns and I would only like one.  For instance, it currently shows:

```
John Brown                       john@email.com
Sue Fields                       sue@email.com
Mark Twain                       mark.twain@email.com
```

and I'd like it to only show:

```
John Brown
Sue Fields
Mark Twain
```

Here's the code for my adapter:

```
public class POCInfoAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    //Private objects.
    private List<POCInfo> mListPOCInfo;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    //constructor.
    public POCInfoAdapter(Context c, List<POCInfo> list){
        mListPOCInfo = list;

        //create layout inflater.
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(c);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount(){
        return mListPOCInfo.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position){
        return mListPOCInfo.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position){
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        //Get view reference.
        View view = convertView;

        //If view is null.
        if(view == null){
            //Inflate new layout.
            view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.poc_list, null);

            //create holder.
            ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();

            //Find Controls.
            holder.txtFullName = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtFullName);
            holder.txtEmailAddress = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtEmailAddress);

            //Set data structure to view.
            view.setTag(holder);
        }

        //Get selected POC Info.
        POCInfo pocInfo = mListPOCInfo.get(position);

        if(pocInfo != null){
            //query data structure.
            ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();

            //Set data to display.
            holder.txtFullName.setText(pocInfo.getFullName());
            holder.txtEmailAddress.setText(pocInfo.getEmailAddress());
        }

        return view;
    }

    //Class to hold data structure on view with POC Information.
    static class ViewHolder{
        private TextView txtFullName;
        private TextView txtEmailAddress;
    }
}
```

and the code to populate the spinner:

```
Spinner spSpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spPOCs);
spSpinner.setAdapter(new POCInfoAdapter(this, DBAdapter.queryAll()));
```

DBAdapter.queryAll() returns a List of type POCInfo.  The POCInfoAdapter class is also used by many other activities which require the email address so I can't just change the getView() to only return FullName.

Any ideas?

Comment: remove this line  holder.txtEmailAddress =  (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtEmailAddress);

Comment: As I said in the 2nd to last line of the OP, I can't change the getView because this class is used in other Activities where it is required.

Comment: ...then create a copy of the class and remove it and use that...or have a flag that will hide it and set that flag accordingly

Comment: @JeremyS - so if I need different "Views" of my Adapter, I need to create a new class for each one?  That doesn't sound too logical...what if I needed 5-10 different views?  Samir - not too sure what you're referring to in your last comment....sry.

Comment: Use flags then. Set booleans to show which textviews need to be shown

Comment: Thanks JeremyS, this works great.  Question though, how can I get my spinner to have radio buttons?  I can't seem to find where to use 'android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item'

Answer (score 0):

no matter how many items you want to display, including radio button, you can configure them in your customized layout. and you can inflate this layout by your code

```
view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.poc_list, null);
```